# vertical jquery megamenu plugin submenu on page load

Tags: jquery, css, menu, megamenu

I am using jquery Vertical Mega menu from http://www.designchemical.com  when my page loads it first shows all of the menus (including the sub menus) for a split second as it renders and then the submenus disappear and it looks like a normal vertical menu.

I tried using the below solution given for horizontal mega menu but that is not working...

```
#mega-1 li ul {
    display: none;
}

#mega-1 .sub ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Please suggest how to make it work

html code

```
<ul id="mega-1" class="mega-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Header 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Header 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Header 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post your html as well. Is your `#menu` div or ul?

Comment: hi i am using code from this site http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin/getting-started/

Comment: So leave just first block of your code and should be ok

Comment: sorry I didnt get you...

Comment: Remove this block of code `#menu .sub ul {
    display: block;
}` and post the results

Comment: I tried removing  that but then sub menu are not visible...

Comment: Try to add only `ul.sub {display: none;}`

Comment: still same problem sub menu are not visible... only a line appears...

Comment: It can't be true, because when jQuery finishes loading menu it adds a style to `<ul class="sub" style="display: block;">`. Inline style overrides styles applied from your css file.

Comment: Dunno but it still gives error morpheus..

Comment: Will post live link so dat youll can help me

Answer (score 0):

*Without seeing the page to debug, it's difficult to say for sure 100% but I would imagine the following ...*

To avoid any content jumps, make sure the nested UL is hidden with CSS and not relying on JavaScript to hide the sub menus. If you are using Firebug or Chrome, inspect the code while JavaScript is disabled to make sure you have no styles overwriting your display:none; on the first UL directly under Menu Item A.

Also, if the purpose of `#menu .sub ul { display: block; }` is for your second level nested UL to stay as a block element, you are missing the .sub class from their LI parents, so add a class of .sub to your sub-header LIs.